# how to handle the Exception in spark map() function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to ignore Exception in map() function , for example:

```
rdd.map(_.toInt)
```

where rdd is a `RDD[String]`.

but if it meets non-number string, it will failed.

what is the easist way to ignore any Exception and ignore that line? (I do not want to use filter to handle exception, because there may be so many other exceptions...)

Comment: Don't require pure functions to deal with exceptions: filter first.

Comment: I don't really think filter is a good idea, because I could not enumerate all possible errors now... so the running program maybe failed suddenly in some day...

Comment: Not at all. The filter only accepts values which cannot throw an exception on parsing: strings that are parseable as integers, which is well-defined. The the `toInt` function can "throw random errors", then you're in another pickle (and a different question).

Answer (score 21):

You can use a combination of [Try](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.util.Try) and map/filter.

Try will wrap your computation into Success, if they behave as expected, or Failure, if an exception is thrown. Then you can filter what you want - in this case the successful computations, but you could also filter the error cases for logging purposes, for example.

The following code is a possible starting point. You can run and explore it in [scastie.org](http://scastie.org/9296) to see if it fits your needs.

```
import scala.util.Try

object Main extends App {

  val in = List("1", "2", "3", "abc")

  val out1 = in.map(a => Try(a.toInt))
  val results = out1.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)

  println(results)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to use filter/map

```
rdd.filter(r=>NumberUtils.isNumber(r)).map(r=> r.toInt)
```

or flatmap

```
exampleRDD.flatMap(r=> {if (NumberUtils.isNumber(r)) Some(r.toInt) else  None})
```

Otherwise you can catch exception in map function

```
myRDD.map(r => { try{
        r.toInt
    }catch {
        case runtime: RuntimeException => {
        -1
        }
    }
})
```

and then apply filter(on -1)

Comment: is there other manners?
I don't really think filter is a good idea, because I could not enumerate all possible errors now... so the running program maybe failed suddenly in some day...

Comment: How can u use scala option with rdd's flatMap?

Comment: @sb' According to docs RDD flatMap takes function witch returns TraversableOnce. Maybe im missing something but it looks like this code does not type checks?

Comment: Now i see there is implicit conversion between Option and  TravesableOnce.