# Spark exception handling for json

Tags: json, scala, exception, apache-spark

I am trying to catch/ignore a parsing error when I'm reading a json file

```
val DF = sqlContext.jsonFile("file")
```

There are a couple of lines that aren't valid json objects, but the data is too large to go through individually (~1TB)

I've come across exception handling for mapping using `import scala.util.Try`and `in.map(a => Try(a.toInt))` referencing:
[how to handle the Exception in spark map() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024052/how-to-handle-the-exception-in-spark-map-function)

How would I catch an exception when reading a json file with the function `sqlContext.jsonFile`?

Thanks!

Comment: When reading json, you can apply `.option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")` to ignore bad records or `.option("mode","FAILFAST")` to interrupt the job with a useful exception. [See the docs for more detail](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are out of luck here. `DataFrameReader.json` which is used under the hood is pretty much all-or-nothing. If your input contains malformed lines you have to filter these manually. A basic solution could look like this:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._

val df = sqlContext.read.json(
    sc.textFile("file").filter(JSON.parseFull(_).isDefined)
)
```

Since above validation is rather expensive you may prefer to drop `jsonFile` / `read.json` completely and to use parsed JSON lines directly.

Comment: May I suggest `isDefined` instead of `match { ... }`?

Comment: By all means. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @zero323! It is a lot slower, but it works and there's nothing wrong with letting the job run over night :)

Comment: You can try different parsing libraries. I think that Spark is internally using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Using `mapPartitions` instead of `map` could improve performance as well.